# How to access shared bean instance across different classes that returns an integer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a config class where I have configured a Bean method that returns an integer and I am passing this bean instance in the constructor of two more classes. In first class I am incrementing this bean method, wanted to access incremented count in second class. In first class bean instance(Integer) is incrementing, but not persisting that value to second class where still I get '0' for this bean instance. How I can persist the same value to second class ? Default bean scope is singleton, so that is taken care. Anything am I doing wrong?

```
@Configuration
public class LineConfig {

 @Bean(name = "getCount")
   public Integer getCount()
    {
        return new Integer(0);
    }

//pls ingnore other logic/syntax as I am focussing only on bean method
 public Step processinvoicejobStep(String fileName,int chunkSize,String jobString) {
           mongoFailedRecordList=new ArrayList<>();
               Step step;       
                  step =  stepBuilderFactory
                        .get("processinvoiceErrjob"+"-"+fileName)
                        .<invoiceWrapper,invoiceWrapper> chunk(chunkSize)
                        .reader(new invoiceReader(container, azureBlobinvoiceErr,azureBlobinvoiceParsingErr))
         **class 1 <----**.writer(new invoiceWriter(mongoConfig.mongoDB().getCollection(collectionName),mongoConfig.mongoDB(),mongoFailedRecordList,fileName,azureBlobinvoiceErr,azureBlobinvoiceErr,objectMapper,enableStats,threadPool,env,container,writeList,**getInsertCount()**))
        **class 2 <----** .listener(new WriterListener(mongoFailedRecordList,env,container,fileName,azureBlobinvoiceErr,errorData(),writeList,**getCount()**)).build();

                return step;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the constructors of the two classes your passing the Integer Bean to?

Comment: Is Step instance returned by processinvoicejobStep a spring managed bean ?

Comment: @R.G no, step instance is not managed by spring, job triggered by rest endpoint.

Comment: I assume you are creating the Step instance with a new operator and calling the method processInvoiceJobStep() on that instance ?